# Redirect standard output produced by a call to a C function from Julia using ccall

Tags: julia

I am making a Julia wrapper for a C/C++ library. The C/C++ functions that I am wrapping write to standard output. Is there a way to redirect those messages from the Julia side without commenting/removing the write statements from the C/C++ code?

Comment: You could use JuliaIO's `Suppressor.@suppress` macro: https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl Their macros use streams redirects underneath for you. Could you provide a simple code example of how you are doing the wrapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `redirect_stdout` for this.

```
oldstd = stdout
redirect_stdout(somewhere_else)
ccall(:printf, Cint, (Cstring,), "Hello World!")
Base.Libc.flush_cstdio() # it might be necessary to flush C stdio to maintain the correct order of outputs or forcing a flush
redirect_stdout(oldstd) # recover original stdout
```

You may want to use `redirect_stdout(f::Function, stream)` method instead. Here, `f` should be a function taking no parameter (i.e. like `() -> do_something(...)`). This method automatically recovers the stream to `stdout`. Using `do` syntax;

```
redirect_stdout(somewhere) do
    ccall(:printf, Cint, (Cstring,), "Hello World!")
    Base.Libc.flush_cstdio() # might be needed
end
```